# Export (default) class in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, syntax, reactjs, ecmascript-6

If I'm creating a component, it seems you can create a class in a lot of different ways. What is the difference between these? How do I know which one to use?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {

}

export const Header = React.createClass({

})

export default React.createClass({

})
```

I'm just assuming they do different things, or is it just different syntax?

If someone could give me a quick explanation, or a link, I would really appreciate it. I don't want to start out with a new framework not knowing exactly what the difference is.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Hi and welcome to React!

I think part of what you're having trouble with here is not really React-specific, but instead related to the new ES2015 module syntax.  When creating React class components, for most intents and purposes you can think of `React.createClass` as functionally equivalent to `class MyComponent extends React.Component`.  One is just using the new ES2015 class syntax whereas the other is using the pre-ES2015 syntax.

For learning about modules, I'd recommend reading a few articles on the new module syntax to get familiar with it.  Here's a good one to start with:  http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html.

So in short, these are just differences in syntax, but I'll attempt to do a quick walk-through:

```
/**
 * This is how you import stuff.  In this case you're actually 
 * importing two things:  React itself and just the "Component" 
 * part from React.  Importing the "Component" part by itself makes it
 * so that you can do something like:
 *
 * class MyComponent extends Component ...
 * 
 * instead of...
 * 
 * class MyComponent extends React.Component
 * 
 * Also note the comma below
 */
import React, {Component} from 'react';


/**
 * This is a "default" export.  That means when you import 
 * this module you can do so without needing a specific module
 * name or brackets, e.g.
 * 
 * import Header from './header';
 *
 * instead of...
 *
 * import { Header } from './header';
 */
export default class Header extends Component {

}

/**
 * This is a named export.  That means you must explicitly
 * import "Header" when importing this module, e.g.
 *
 * import { Header } from './header';
 *
 * instead of...
 * 
 * import Header from './header';
 */
export const Header = React.createClass({

})

/**
 * This is another "default" export, only just with a 
 * little more shorthand syntax.  It'd be functionally 
 * equivalent to doing:
 *
 * const MyClass = React.createClass({ ... });
 * export default MyClass;
 */
export default React.createClass({

})
```

Comment: This is a good article on modules: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/