# How to call a class function from another in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two classes club, clubs and the main app class. In the clubs class i'm getting a list of club and I am displaying them in a `<ul>` list. In the `club` class I'm trying the get the detail of the clicked item from the clubs list. The point is I don't know how to call the detail function present in the `club` class in the `clubs` class.

Here's the details:

The **Club** class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const clubData = id => `urlto`

class Club extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  requestFailed: false
}
// This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
this.clubDetail = this.clubDetail.bind(this);
}

clubDetail(id) {
console.log('karim')
{/*fetch(clubData(id)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error("Failed connection to the API")
    }

    return response
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      club: response
    })
  }, () => {
    this.setState({
      requestFailed: true
    })
  })*/}
}

render() {
if(!this.state.club) return <h1>No club selected !</h1>
return (
  <ul>
    <li>Name : {this.state.club.name}</li>
    <li>Email : {this.state.club.email}</li>
    <li>Website : {this.state.club.website}</li>
  </ul>
);
 }
}

 export default Club;
```

**Clubs** class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const clubsList = `urlto`


class Clubs extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  requestFailed: false
}
}

componentDidMount() {
fetch(clubsList)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error("Failed connection to the API")
    }

    return response
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      clubs: response
    })
  }, () => {
    this.setState({
      requestFailed: true
    })
  })
 }

 render() {
if(!this.state.clubs) return <h1>No results</h1>
return (
  <div>
    <ul>
    {this.state.clubs.map(function(item) {
        return <a key={item.id} onClick={Club.clubDetail(item.id)}><li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li></a>
    })}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default Clubs;
```

In the onClick prop, I've made this call `{Club.clubDetail(item.id)}` but it seems not working

The main app class:

```
  class App extends Component {
   render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="App-left-side">
      <Clubs></Clubs>
    </div>
    <div className="App-center-side">
      <div className="App-center-side-content">
      <Club></Club>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
 }
 }

export default App;
```

Comment: You are trying to call Child to Parent that is not the correct way you have to pass the Onclickevent into props and use it , that is what composition will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Clubs` and `Club` components are used just to displace the data, so i will suggest to make the `api` call from `App` component, and pass the data to `Clubs` component along with an onClick function. Whenever user clicks on any item, pass the id to parent and displace the details of clicked item in `Club` component.

Like this:

**App Component:**

```
const clubsList = `urlto`;

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            requestFailed: false,
            clubs: [],
            club: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(clubsList)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error("Failed connection to the API")
            }
            return response
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                clubs: response
            })
        }, () => {
            this.setState({
                requestFailed: true
            })
        })
    }

    click = (id) => {
        console.log('clicked item', id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="App-left-side">
                    <Clubs clubs={this.state.clubs} clicked={this.click}/>
                </div>
                <div className="App-center-side">
                    <div className="App-center-side-content">
                        <Club club={this.state.club}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Clubs Component:**

```
class Clubs extends Component {

    render() {
        if(!this.props.clubs.length) return <h1>No results</h1>

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.props.clubs.map((item) => {
                        return <a key={item.id} onClick={() => this.props.clicked(item.id)}>
                                  <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
                              </a>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Clubs;
```

**Club Component:**

```
class Club extends Component {

    render() {
        if(!Object.keys(this.props.club)) return <h1>No club selected !</h1>;

        return (
            <ul>
                <li>Name : {this.props.club.name}</li>
                <li>Email : {this.props.club.email}</li>
                <li>Website : {this.props.club.website}</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default Club;
```

Comment: I got this error when i click on one of the items. TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
onClick
src/clubs.js:15

Comment: i changed the map part, are you using the arrow function, like this: `{this.props.clubs.map((item) => {` check the clubs component and use it in the same way it should work.

Comment: In the clubs component you should make e.g :  var props = this.props and change the onClick proprety onClick={() => props.clicked(item.id)}. Thanks dude

Comment: because this.props refer the the current element off the map loop

Answer (score 0):

For `reactjs` to use another class you will need to [export](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34841313/7707749) it:

```
export default class Club extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      password: ''
    };
  };
}
```

Remember that `React.createClass` has a built-in magic feature that bound all methods to `this` automatically for you. This can be a little confusing for `JavaScript` developers that are not used to this feature in other classes, or it can be confusing when they move from React to other classes.

The proper use of the [feature](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding):

```
class Clubs extends React.Component {
  Club = () => {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Basically said:

```
export default class Club extends Component {
```

Is what you were forgetting to do and maybe the call to the class itself. Hope this solution might help you out!