# How to prevent rendering on change

Tags: react-native

I have the following script. I'm running on a pc using create-react-native-app.  The console gives me the following warnings.  I'm not sure what to do about them if anything.

Here are the warnings:

```
Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated and will be removed in the 
next major version. Use static getDerivedStateFromProps instead.

Please update the following components: TouchableOpacity

Learn more about this warning here:
hxxxx/fb.me/react-async-component-lifecycle-hooks
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:82:15 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:5706:19 in printWarning
- ... 19 more stack frames from framework internals
19:26:44: Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in 
the next major version. Use componentDidMount instead. As a temporary 
workaround, you can rename to UNSAFE_componentWillMount.

Please update the following components: TouchableOpacity

Learn more about this warning here:
hxxx/fb.me/react-async-component-lifecycle-hooks
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:82:15 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:5706:19 in printWarning
- ... 19 more stack frames from framework internals
19:26:46: Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated and will be 
removed in the next major version. Use static getDerivedStateFromProps 
instead.

Please update the following components: Text, TextInput, View

Learn more about this warning here:
hxxx/fb.me/react-async-component-lifecycle-hooks
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:82:15 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:5706:19 in printWarning
- ... 21 more stack frames from framework internals
19:26:48: Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in 
the next major version. Use componentDidMount instead. As a temporary 
workaround, you can rename to UNSAFE_componentWillMount.

Please update the following components: TouchableHighlight

Learn more about this warning here:
hxxx/fb.me/react-async-component-lifecycle-hooks
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:82:15 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:5706:19 in printWarning
- ... 23 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I'm having the following 2 problems with the code:

1. On each change of the input field the app renders.  I need to suppress the render until `onSubmitEditing` is called
2. When the code runs I get a yellow warning on my IOS device;

> Warning:componentWillMount is deprecated...

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput,Button, StyleSheet, View,Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import {Constants} from 'expo'

  let id=0
  const Todo = (props) => (
    <Text>
      {/* <input type='checkbox'
              checked={props.todo.checked}
              onClick={props.onToggle}
        /> */}
       <Button title='delete' button onPress={props.onDelete}></Button>
       <Text>{props.todo.text}</Text>
    </Text>
  )
  export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
      super()
      this.state={
        todos:[],
        inputText:''
      }
    }

  clearText(){
    this.setState({inputText:''})

  }



  addTodo(text){
    console.log(text)

    this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos,
                              { id:id++,
                                text: text,
                                checked:false
                              }
                          ]
                  })

    this.setState({inputText:text})



  }
  toggle(id){
    this.setState({todos: this.state.todos.map(todo=>{
                          if(id!==todo.id)return todo
                          return{
                              id:todo.id,
                              text:todo.text,
                              checked: !todo.checked}})})
  }
  removeTodo(id){
    this.setState({todos: this.state.todos.filter(todo=>(todo.id!==id))})
  }

  render(){
     console.log(this.state)
     return(

       <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text >Count of Todos: &nbsp;{this.state.todos.length}</Text>
          <Text >{"Todo's checked:"}&nbsp;
               {this.state.todos.filter(todo =>(todo.checked===true)).length}</Text>
          <TextInput
                 style={{height:25,borderColor:'red',borderWidth:1,textAlign:'center'}}
                 value={this.state.inputText}
                  placeholder={'add Todo'}
                  onSubmitEditing={()=>{this.clearText()}}
                  onChangeText={(text) => {this.addTodo(text)}}
                  />

          <ScrollView>
           {this.state.todos.map(todo=>(
                 <Todo
                    onToggle={()=>(this.toggle(todo.id))}
                    onDelete={()=>(this.removeTodo(todo.id))}
                    todo={todo}
                    key={todo.id}
                 />))}
          </ScrollView>
       </View>
     )
    }
  }
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    height:50,

    paddingTop:3*Constants.statusBarHeight,

  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure components defined as function will always re-render.

Convert the component to a class and prevent the re-render in [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) returning false.

The signature is shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState). Say you for not re-render is that the componet's params haven't changed:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
   return !equals(nextProps, this.props);
}
```

i think that this example could help you as it's well explained with examples: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

after all it's about creating a class with methods inside and call it as usually in an OOP language.

Hope it helps you

Comment: will that also fix the warning message?

Comment: also, when I try that I get cannot call a class as a function.  how do I modify  {this.state.todos.map(todo=>(
                 <Todo

Comment: you have to call it as class method, not as a function... check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494652/how-to-call-a-class-function-from-another-in-reactjs

Comment: I'm lost, example doesn't help. how do I change that line of code?

Comment: edited, check the last link i pasted, i only used react once and i find it easy to understand, you must check the doc before asking for next time, it's a nice habit :)

Comment: link really doesn't help

Comment: i really can't explain you how to work with object oriented programing languages using SO comments or posts, you really need to read some doc and follow some tutorials to learn basics...

Comment: Can you explain why this doesn't work or show how to fix it?  {this.state.todos.map(todo=>{
                 <Todo
                    onToggle={()=>(this.toggle(todo.id))}
                    onDelete={()=>(this.removeTodo(todo.id))}
                    todo={todo}
                    key={todo.id}
                 />})}