# Attempted import error: './components' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following ReactJS project structure and I'm getting the following error:

> ./src/index.js
>
> Attempted import error: './components' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').

My goal is to import components like this: `import { App, Navbar } from 'components';` (notice the 'components') and not like `./components/App`, `./components/App/index` or so. To do that, I needed to add index.js in the components directory. I tried doing that by the following code, but I'm receiving the error above.

What's the reason? How do I solve it?

There are similar threads, but I'm already exporting it by `export default App;` in ./components/App/index.jsx. Maybe the reason is the .jsx extension?

[image]

- index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

- components/index.js

```
export App from './App';
```

- components/App/index.jsx

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotAuthorizedRoute from '../../common/NotAuthorizedRoute';
import { Navbar, Home, User, Login } from 'components';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/users" component={User} />
          <NotAuthorizedRoute path="/sign-in" component={Login} />
          <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
        </Switch>

      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

- components/App/style.css

## What I tried:

I tried doing the following, like people said in this thread: [Attempted import error: 'App' is not exported from './App'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868946/attempted-import-error-app-is-not-exported-from-app).

- components/index.js

```
export { App } from './App'; // note the brackets
```

But then I got:

```
./src/components/index.js
Attempted import error: 'App' is not exported from './App'.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you are having some confusions with ES6 [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)/[import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) syntaxes. MDN documentation is very explicative, I would recommend you to check it.

The most important thing is to remember the difference between default and named export/import. (HINT: When you see brackets in export/import statements you are dealing with named ones)

In your specific case, you will have to do as follows:

- ./components/component-a.jsx

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  return (
    <MyComponent/>
  );
};

export {ComponentA};
```

- ./components/component-b.jsx

```
const ComponentB = () => {
  return (
    <MyComponent/>
  );
};

export {ComponentB};
```

- ./components/index.js

```js
import {componentA} from './component-a.jsx';
import {componentB} from './component-b.jsx';

export {componentA, componentB};
```

- ./some-file.jsx

```
import {componentA, componentB} from './components';
```

- ./some-other-file.jsx

```
import {componentA} from './components';
```

This is the typical pattern to create a virtual export/import namespace for logical module classification.

Please note that I've not used default exports. There are several opinions about this, but I would recommend to not use them to avoid errors like the one you are having.

Please also note that you'll always have to specify the full relative path to the `components` directory. The only way to import things from `'components'` is by having a `components` package installed in your `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Thank you! Nice explanation! I wonder why the similar thread didn't describe it as you did.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using the exported value componentA in {componentA}

```
remove `{}` and check
```